# SVA for the following protocol

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

[I have to write a single SVA for the complete protocol shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhExJ.jpg)

I wrote the following SVA but it doesn't capture the immediate ack. How do I fix that

```
@(posedge clk) 
  $rose(val) |=> 
    ( $stable(data) && !ack && val ) ##[1:64] ( ack && val ) ##1 ( !ack && !val )
```

Comment: how did you test? do you have a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your assertion, it won't capture the immediate ACK because you are expecting a sequence excluding an immediate ACK with `!ack`. I would re-write your assertion as:

```
sequence seq;
  $stable({address, data}) ##[0:63] (val && ack && $stable({address, data})) ##1 !ack ##1 !val;
endsequence
 
property p;
  @(posedge clk) 
     $rose(val) |=> seq;
endproperty

as_protocol : assert property(p);
```